# Probability on a disc

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry

I was solving some questions of probability and I came across the following one:

*Question:* Given an arbitrary disc with radius $r> 0$. A point is chosen randomly on the disk. Determine the probability of the chosen point being closer to the disc boundary than to the disc center.

I have no idea how to begin to resolve such an issue.

Thanks for the comments and solutions.

Comment: Try drawing a picture of a disc of radius 1 to first determine which points are closer to the boundary than the disc center.

Comment: I dont understand " points are closer to the boundary than the disc center".  You might need a definition or a response below how I make such a question. I've tried using geometric probability, but I can not determine the points that are closer to boundary than the center of the disk.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the disc has radius $r$. Suppose a point $a$ is of distance $d$ from the centre. Then, its distance from the boundary is $(r-d)$ (the distance of a point from the boundary is defined as the least distance from the point over all points of the boundary). Hence, a point is closer to the disc of the boundary than the centre if $(r-d) > d$, that is, when $d > r/2$.

So now that we have a clear definition of the set we are looking for, now we can look at geometric probability. The complement of the set we are looking for is the smaller disc of radius $r/2$. Hence it will have area $\pi r^2/4$.

Hence the final probability will be $(1 - \frac{\pi r^2/4}{\pi r^2})$ = $\frac{3}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

Let's calculate this probability for $r=1$.

If random vector $(X,Y)$ has uniform distribution on disk $\{(x,y)\mid ||(x,y||\leq 1\}$ and $R:=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ then for $s\in(0,1)$:$$P(R\leq s)=\frac{\lambda(\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\leq s^2\})}{\lambda(\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\leq 1\}}=\frac{\pi s^2}{\pi }=s^2$$

where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^2$.

Based on that we find that: $$P\left(R>\frac12\right)=1-\frac14=\frac34$$

For a general $r>0$ we will find the same outcome, because in that case we just use a different standard.